# Npx localtunnel no longer displaying a URL

Tags: streamlit, ngrok, npx

I basically have been using stream lit for the past few days and used a npx local tunnel to deploy it from google Colab, but now it is saying that the npx has been produced, but no link/url is given. It was just working a few days ago, now with the same exact code, the block just runs forever and the url is not given. There is even an example online that shows how to deploy a streamlit app from Colab and even that is no longer working. https://colab.research.google.com/github/mrm8488/shared_colab_notebooks/blob/master/Create_streamlit_app.ipynb#scrollTo=XTGAizLhOIgC

I have tried other approaches to deploying my streamlit app but they all do not work or return errors, I have also tried using different versions of streamlit. I have tried different laptops and different internets as well. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RdGR.jpg)